# Every proper ideal $I$ in a nonzero commutative unitary ring $R$ is contained in a maximal ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

> If $R$ is a nonzero commutative unitary ring, then $R$ has a maximal ideal. Indeed, every proper ideal $I$ in $R$ is contained in a maximal ideal.

There is a proof of this in Rotman's *Advanced Modern Algebra*, but there is something that I do not get in the second paragraph...

[image]

In the second paragraph of the proof, it says "Let $X$ be the family of all proper ideals containing *I* partially ordered by inclusion...". I'm not sure why we can assume that inclusion gives us a partial order. If we look at the ring $\Bbb{Z}$, for instance, we see that the ideal $(0)$ is contained in both $(2)$ and $(3)$. However, it is not true that $(2) \subseteq (3)$ or that $(3) \subseteq (2)$.

Comment: That's okay for a partial order.  See the [definition here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set).

Comment: Speaking of $\,\Bbb Z,\,$ you might find it instructive to specialize the proof to $\,\Bbb Z\,$ (or any PID). Whenever some abstract result is not clear, one should look at more concrete specializations to gain insight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A **partial** order needn't be **total**, there are, as you noted, incomparable elements. Recall that a *partial* order on a set $X$ is an antisymmetric, reflexive and transitive relation $R\subseteq X\times X$.